# getData function not finishing result (no error) [Google Script]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to transfer data from the first spreadsheet and transfer the data within the range given below, into a second spreadsheet. I am able to run the script and everything seems fine, however it does not return an error message, nor compile the code correctly.

I am asking to see if I am using my functions correctly or if I am mis-referencing something. Please see the log below, in order to display the "complete" execution.

Thank you for any and all help.

```js
[17-09-26 12:38:57:868 PDT] Starting execution
[17-09-26 12:38:57:977 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.openById([1fVooVTPgkiVr5rY1g-uKhjHIs1up5DJ3B9l_joleC9Q]) [0.102 seconds]
[17-09-26 12:38:57:977 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Heather]) [0 seconds]
[17-09-26 12:38:58:106 PDT] Sheet.getRange([A1:G300]) [0.127 seconds]
[17-09-26 12:38:58:362 PDT] Range.getValues() [0.256 seconds]
[17-09-26 12:38:58:364 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0.001 seconds]
[17-09-26 12:38:58:465 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Heather]) [0.1 seconds]
[17-09-26 12:38:59:050 PDT] Sheet.getRange([A1:G300]) [0.584 seconds]
[17-09-26 12:38:59:057 PDT] Range.setValues([[[ID, Vendor, Address, Due Date, Time, I or E, $$$], [Mon Sep 25 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2017, , , , , , ], [Tue Sep 26 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2017, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ], [, , , , , , ]]]...) [0.003 seconds]
[17-09-26 12:38:59:729 PDT] Execution succeeded [1.183 seconds total runtime]
```

```js
function getdata() {
  var sourcess = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fVooVTPgkiVr5rY1g-uKhjHIs1up5DJ3B9l_joleC9Q");  //source spreadsheet
  var sourcesheet = sourcess.getSheetByName("Stephen-GA");  //source sheet name
  var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A1:G300');  //data range source
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //destination spreadsheet (the current active spreadsheet)
  var destsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stephen-GA");  //destination sheet name
  var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A1:G300');  //destination range


  destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works okay for me:
I had a little trouble getting auto-completion to work so I deleted all of the comments and reformatted the text.

```
function getMyData() 
{
  var sourcess=SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyID");
  var sourcesheet = sourcess.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A1:B4');
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A1:B4');
  destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Cooper. I just tried it and it appears to have worked. I am not sure how familiar you are with the rules in this language, but do you think the "-" in sheet name might have messed it up? Or possibly a too large of range? I appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think either of those things are a problem.

Comment: All right, well do you think it might possibly be Google Script? I tried testing the script twice in a row and it didn't complete the second time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the Execution Transcript

Comment: It says nothing other than "Execution Succeeded"

Comment: I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: It's all good. You have been a great help and I believe you have solved my issue. Thanks.